# Is it acceptable to store the one-to-many relationship in a single table, having child entities flattened into a string column?

Tags: android, database-design

Editing my previous question, which boils down to this:

Given the following data structure (object composition):

[image]

is it bad design, or is it acceptable, that instead of two related tables, I store the sets of Reminders into a string column of Event table in some serialized way (e.g. JSON):

[image]

given that it would simplify my application significantly?

The reasons why I am considering this are:

- I don't need the flexibility of accessing Reminders separately;
- I always need to query all Reminders per Event and process them in code (e.g. choose the next three reminders based on time and weekday_flags — which is not trivial to do with a `where` clause);
- In the end I need to display a list of Events with associated Reminders as stated above, so ideally I already have a dataset (cursor) with size matching the number of Events that I can feed to the adapter, and not the large join result that needs further processing and re-indexing;
- Reminder entity is small and is not going to have more fields in the future, and there usually won't be more than 3-4 reminders per event, therefore storing them as a serialized string is not a size or migration concern.

As pointed out by [Christophe Beyls here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/117318275691309984021/posts/FV4LL3UuJ2a), the system's serialization/parceling mechanisms cannot be used to persist data because they might change eventually. So it's either JSON or some custom lightweight delimited format.

Comment: I do not quite understand why the downvotes and close requests. Is it off-topic, or a dumb question, or what?

Comment: In all seriousness, maybe you should be asking "What bad things might happen if I try this?"  It sounds to me like you know the trade-offs and have good technical reasons to do it your way so I'd say give it a try.  The pure answer is always full normalization but in the real-world sometimes denormalization can pay big performance dividends. Just go into it with your eyes open.

Comment: Now that you've edited your question, I've voted to reopen it.  Basically, there is only one scenario I know of where keeping delimited data is better then keeping it normalized, and that's when your database have no interaction with the data at all (not even search inside), and your application needs the data delimited.  your question seems to indicate that your situation is what I've described, therefor it might be acceptable.

Comment: @KellyS.French Thank you. Actually I don't know how to further edit this question without losing the context. "What are disadvantages of denormalization" would again be too broad, and generally explained even by a Wikipedia article on the subject. I actually almost always choose normalization; this situation here is different because it's Android where performance matters, and normalization would bring extra complexity for the sake of unneeded flexibility.

Comment: I would use the 2 tables approach as it models better the real world object implementation.